# How to prevent firefox/chrome from sleeping

Tags: browser

I use this site http://kukuklok.com/ as my alarm clock. It used to work just fine in chrome but I noticed a couple months ago that it would sometimes fail to go off at the right time but as soon as I brought the browser window into focus it would sound.

I then switched to firefox (54 I think) and it worked fine. However I recently upgraded to the latest firefox and it has shown the same symptoms.

My computer (Win 10 Pro) does not sleep however the screen does shut off.

How do I fix this issue?